# memory error on web.datareader using pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, yahoo-finance

I have a block of code that functions, however, I get memory errors or extremely long run times, is there a more elegant solution that requires less memory or can be run in a shorter time period?

```
import pandas as pd
import pandas.io.data as web
import datetime

#Grabs tickers from html 
exchList = pd.read_html('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_S%26P_500_companies', infer_types=False)
sp500 = []
for ticker in exchList[0][0][1:]:
   sp500.append(ticker)
sp500 = [w.replace('.','-') for w in sp500]

#sets date for data fetch
start = datetime.datetime(2000,1,1)
end =  datetime.date.today()

#fetches data from yahoo and prints to csv
p = web.DataReader(sp500, "yahoo", start, end)
main_df = p.to_frame()
noIndex = main_df.reset_index()
noIndex.columns.values[1]= 'Name'
indexed = noIndex.set_index('Date')
csv = indexed.to_csv('edata.csv')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`import pandas.io.data` is deprecated in modern Pandas versions:

```
In [113]: import pandas.io.data
...
ImportError: The pandas.io.data module is moved to a separate package (pandas-datareader). After installing the pandas-datareader package (h
ttps://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas-datareader), you can change the import ``from pandas.io import data, wb`` to ``from pandas_datareader im
port data, wb``.
```

So we should use `pandas_datareader` instead:

```
from pandas_datareader import data as web

url = 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_S%26P_500_companies'
sp500 = pd.read_html(url)[0].iloc[1:, 0].str.replace('\.', '-')
df = web.DataReader(sp500, "yahoo", '2000-01-01').to_frame()
```

Memory usage:

```
In [112]: df.memory_usage()
Out[112]:
Index         7974167
Open         15870936
High         15870936
Low          15870936
Close        15870936
Volume       15870936
Adj Close    15870936
dtype: int64
```

Execution time:

```
In [115]: %timeit -n 1 -r 1 web.DataReader(sp500, "yahoo", '2000-01-01').to_frame()
1 loop, best of 1: 1min 57s per loop
```